# docker image python3.10 and python3-pip always have a security vulnerability

Tags: python, docker

I always get the
security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-20107 error,
even if i just have this commands for docker file
is there a way to fix this.

```
FROM debian:stable 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ 
python3.10 \
python3-pip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-20107) you've shown also informs you that the vulnerable package is fixed in `python 3.10.7`, which is available in debian sid. Either switch your docker image to [sid](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/debian/sid-slim/images/sha256-744464ba95b3ca63e9084ab66ab90f923ccd8b464824314aaa4c54f237030a4a?context=explore), or just ignore the warning and make sure any application you are running is not using the affected module.

Comment: That doesn't help. The security issue doesn't showup when i create image only using this line 

"FROM debian:stable "

The line python3-pip is the issue, anyway to fix that line

Comment: @addy can you update your answer with the exact message being shown? I've built the image using the dockerfile you posted and I don't see such a message

Comment: Sorry i take tht back, you're suggestion helped, thank you.